# get a plain-string representation of a double without going through BigDecimal

Tags: java, string, double

With a double number in Java, is it possible to get a plain string representation (Eg., `654987`) instead of the scientific format (Eg., `6.54987E5`) ?

Now I know we can use the `BigDecimal.toPlainString()` method, but creating a `BigDecimal` simply to get a `String` (really?) seems a bit sloppy and inefficient to me. 
Does anyone know of another way?

Answer (score 5):

```
double d = 12345678;

System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(String.format("%.0f", d));
```

```
1.2345678E7
12345678
```

Note that if you only need to print this string representation you can simply use `System.out.printf("%.0f", d)`.

If you don't want any rounding *at all*, then I would stick with what you suggested, namely `(new BigDecimal(d)).toPlainString()`.

Comment: I don't need to print, I just need the string for other use. But your answer seems to work! :) Thanks much. Just to be sure, what's the significance of `%0.f`? Does that mean printing without any fractional-digits (digits AFTER the decimal point) ?

Comment: @user1508893 Yes - in other words it rounds to the nearest integer. You can use `%.1f` to round to 1 decimal place, `%.2f` for two etc.

Comment: Oooh, then this isn't working for me. Is there a way to prevent Java from rounding the number? I wan't the *real* plain string. (not rounded or anything)

Comment: Just `%f` (without the number specifying the width) would work, woudln't it?

Comment: I'm not sure if OP is wanting to do this operation in a small way or at large scale., but if performance at scale is a consideration, String.format() can be a real dog.  I just looked at the implementation of toPlainString() and it seems to be very efficiently written.

Comment: @user1508893 `%f` will round to 6 decimal places.

Comment: @RickGrashel Are you sure `String.format()` is less efficient than `BigDecimal.toPlainString()`

Comment: @user1508893 To be honest I'm not sure I buy that. `toPlainString` might be efficient but you still need to construct a `BigDecimal` instance, which isn't necessarily the fastest thing in the world.

Comment: @user1508893 I've just run some tests, but I can't get the format in any of these posts to produce the level of accuracy that a double holds.  OP is using a double, so I'm presuming that need high-accuracy in the mantissa.  But over 1,000 random doubles (approximately 50 digit mantissa), BigDecimal.toPlainString() produces its output in 250ms whereas String.format produces its output in 350ms.  So 30% better performance.

Comment: @RickGrashel Does 250ms include time spent on creating BigDecimal objects also?

Comment: @user1508890 Yeah, it does.  It was just a simple test.  Two loops iterating over the same list of doubles.  One printed out the BigDecimal.toPlainString().  The other printed out the String.format() pattern.  The test still isn't totally valid, because the pattern given in this thread will not handle a fully accurate double.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) / [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html).

Basic usage from the examples:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
output.println(nf.format(myNumber));
```

For `DecimalFormat`, you can pass in a formatting pattern / locale information for formatting the number.  [This link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) is a good tutorial on using `DecimalFormat`.

Comment: Using this method will add comas(654,987).

Comment: You can use `new DecimalFormat('###.##')` to avoid commas - see the second example in the table in the tutorial linked.

Comment: DecimalFormat works great I agree but is there a way to specify the format with NumberFormat?

Comment: NumberFormat is just the base class for DecimalFormat, and only has a few general purpose factory methods for construction built in - is there a particular reason you can't (or don't want to) use DecimalFormat?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
double number = 654987;

String plain = String.format("%.0f", number);
```